# Converting string with points into decimal number in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, numbers, decimal

I'm trying to implement simple calculator using Objective-C. Here's my problem:

```
_currentNumber = @"4.65";
_num1 = [_currentNum intValue];
```

Obviously, this code above returns "4" instead of 4.65.

How could I make it return a decimal number?

Comment: A quick look into the NSString documentation would probably help. There is a "Getting Numeric Values" section ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `intValue` will return an integer which is not a floating point number.

Use `doubleValue` or `floatValue` ,depending on the precession you need,  to retrieve a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this..

```
NSString *str=@"14.6";
CGFloat value=[str floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.2f",value);
```